# Entity Framework query of order by didn't execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

```
var gridData = uow.Repository<TR>()
                  .GetQueryAsNoTracking()
                  .Include(I => I.CR)
                  .Include(R => R.SystemList)
                  .Include(I => I.Variant)
                  .Include(I => I.ViewComment)
                  .Select(s => new ChangeManagementGridModel()
                               {
                                   TRId = s.TRId,
                                   TRNumber = s.TRNumber,
                                   KemNumber = s.CR.KemNumber,
                                   Country = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.Country.CountryName,
                                   Business = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.Business.Name,
                                   BusinessId = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.BusinessId,
                                   CountryId = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.CountryId,
                                   Variant = s.Variant.VariantName,
                                   ChangeType = s.CR.SystemList.ListValue,
                                   Subject = s.CR.KemSubject,
                                   CreatedByUserName = s.CR.User.UserName,
                                   CreatedOnDate = Convert.ToString(s.CR.CreatedOn),
                                   Status = ""
                               });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(changetype))
        gridData = gridData.Where(x => x.ChangeType.ToLower().Contains(changetype.ToLower()));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createdby))
        gridData = gridData.Where(x => x.CreatedByUserName.ToLower().Contains(createdby.ToLower()));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createdon))
        gridData = gridData.Where(x => x.CreatedOnDate.ToLower().Contains(createdon.ToLower()));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(order))
    {
        if (dir == "asc")
        {
            if (order == "CreatedBy")
                gridData = gridData.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedBy);

            if (order == "CreatedOn")
                gridData = gridData.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn);
        }
        else
        {
            if (order == "CreatedBy")
                gridData = gridData.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedBy);

            if (order == "CreatedOn")
                gridData = gridData.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);
        }
    }
    else
        gridData = gridData.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);

    gridData.ToList();
```

I am trying to query the data from above table and using toList finally to increase the efficiency of the code, but I am not able to do it because of executing the order by statements.

While running through the order by statements I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the query working without the .Select(...) ? I'm not sure but my guess is that you have to do the .Select after the .Where and Order By Statements.

Comment: Set `OrderBy` before `Select` statement. like @hasi05 said.

Comment: If property is not defined in `Select` - you cannot order by that property. I do not see in Select `CreatedBy` and `CreatedOn`.

Comment: And the Include()s have no effect if you use a Select.

Answer (score 0):

Change Select After add wheres and orders to query.

```
var gridData = uow.Repository<TR>()
                  .GetQueryAsNoTracking()
                  .Include(I => I.CR)
                  .Include(R => R.SystemList)
                  .Include(I => I.Variant)
                  .Include(I => I.ViewComment);
//Add Wheres ...
//Add Orders ...
gridData = gridData.Select(s => new ChangeManagementGridModel()
                           {
                               TRId = s.TRId,
                               TRNumber = s.TRNumber,
                               KemNumber = s.CR.KemNumber,
                               Country = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.Country.CountryName,
                               Business = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.Business.Name,
                               BusinessId = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.BusinessId,
                               CountryId = s.Variant.BusinessCountryMapping.CountryId,
                               Variant = s.Variant.VariantName,
                               ChangeType = s.CR.SystemList.ListValue,
                               Subject = s.CR.KemSubject,
                               CreatedByUserName = s.CR.User.UserName,
                               CreatedOnDate = Convert.ToString(s.CR.CreatedOn),
                               Status = ""
                           });
gridData.ToList();
```